# Attributes in XML subtree that belong to the parent

Tags: java, xml, oop, separation-of-concerns

Say I have this XML

```
<doc:document>
  <objects>
    <circle radius="10" doc:colour="red" />
    <circle radius="20" doc:colour="blue" />
  </objects>
</doc:document>
```

And this is how it is parsed (pseudo code):

```
// class DocumentParser
public Document parse(Element edoc) {
     doc = new Document();
     doc.objects = ObjectsParser.parse(edoc.getChild("objects"));

     for ( ...?... ) {
         doc.objectColours.put(object, colour);
     }

     return doc;
}
```

`ObjectsParser` is responsible for parsing the objects bit, but is not and should not be aware of the existence of documents. However, in `Document` colours are associated with objects by use of a `Map`.

What kind of pattern would you recommend to give the colour settings back to `DocumentParser.parse` from `ObjectsParser.parse` so it can associate it with the objects they belong to in a map?

The alternative would be something like this:

```
<doc:document>
  <objects>
    <circle id="1938" radius="10" />
    <circle id="6398" radius="20" />
  </objects>
  <doc:objectViewSettings>
   <doc:objectViewSetting object="1938" colour="red" />
   <doc:objectViewSetting object="6398" colour="blue" />
  </doc:objectViewSettings>
</doc:document>
```

Ugly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea of my own:

```
interface ObjectCreatedFromXmlCallback {
     created(Object object, Element source);
}

// class DocumentParser
public Document parse(Element edoc) {
     doc = new Document();
     doc.objects = ObjectsParser.parse(edoc.getChild("objects"), new ObjectCreatedFromXmlCallback() {
      created(Object o, Element s) {
       if (o instanceof Circle) {
        // read the colour property from s
        doc.objectColours.put(o, colour);
       }
      }
     });

     return doc;
}

// ObjectsParser.parse
c = new Circle();
c.radius = ecircle.getAttribute(...);
callback.created(c, ecircle);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
for (ObjType obj : doc.objects)
{
    doc.objectColours.put(obj, obj.getColour())
}
```

This assumes

1. ObjectsParser returns a
   collection instance implementing
   Iterable
2. ObjType is
   usable as a hash key (implements
   equals() and hashCode() correctly)

Comment: As can be seen by the namespace prefix "doc" on the colour attribute, it only applies in a Document context. An object as created by ObjectsParser will not contain this property.

Comment: Without a description of ObjectsParser it's hard for us to read your mind.  In that case a callback looks like the best solution since you need to get control during parsing.